# Why banners appear on some questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

While browsing some questions I found [this one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/98877/new-job-and-impossible-deadline) where a banner appeared just above the comments section, that indicates:

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

I have never noticed this kind of banners before. *Why and how was that banner added to the question*?

I searched a bit on Meta SE and found the post [Support for banners?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102363/support-for-banners) and wondered if this is related to the banners here in TWP, as it seems to be based on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106374/332286) answer on that post.

Also, *in what cases are those banners added to questions?* I see that the mentioned question already had some long answers before I noticed the banner. I am trying to understand the purpose and benefits of banners here in TWP, so I apologize if this is just my misunderstanding.

Comment: I can say it came as the result of a flag(possibly more than just mine).  This was not the notice I had hoped to see fyi.

Comment: Related Information from Meta.SE: [What are these notices under my post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165006/163292)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a post notice, added by one of the mods.  If a question has been flagged, or in our own browsing of the community we may see an answer that needs improving in some way.  There are a couple of standard post notices that we can apply to give the answerer a focal point for how they may improve their answer.  However, it may still be marked for deletion by high rep members of the community if they so choose.

Not that they actually *do* very often, but at least they have more information as to *how*. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So it is up to mods to decide what posts to put a banner on, so answerers get back on focus of the question? Can non-mod users suggest this banners to be added in some way if they see a post that may require one?

Comment: @GrayCygnus Yes, the mods decide.  Non-mod users can offer a suggestion via a flag that the mods can then determine if a post notice is appropriate.  In some cases the flag itself is spurious as the best way to manage it is to downvote it and/or vote for deletion if you have the rep and you feel it's unsalvageable.

Comment: Yes, I just wondered if it was possible, although I also think it is unnecessary to flag for mod just to add a banner (also may come as annoying or as trying to do mod work when one is not a mod). If the post deserves it most surely a mod will see it and post a banner to it. Also, when I see answers deviating from the point I think that adding a comment on them so the poster can rethink it is another good way to go.

Comment: @GrayCygnus The Workplace is an active site; please don't assume that moderators see everything.  I mean, we try, but we might not always succeed.  If you see something that you think needs attention, please use a flag to let us know.  That's why you *can* flag.  Don't think of it as back-seat driving; think of it as sharing in community maintenance.

Comment: Thanks @MonicaCellio will keep your words in mind. I guess there should be a balance between mod flagging and letting the community handle it organically.

Comment: @GrayCygnus ideally we are exception handlers. SE has a lot of built in processes to allow us as collective users to handle things, from the review queues to even some automatic comment deletion (certain keywords allow single comment flag deletions and I think there's even a threshold of comment flags that auto delete).

Comment: Whoa 3 mods commenting the answer :) great feedback guys